# CursorAdapter for GoogleMaps Activity

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, marker, android-adapter

I wonder if there is any work being done to implement a *Adapter*, e.g. a *CursorAdapter*, which is able to put *Markers* onto a *GoogleMap* hosted by an *Activity* or a *FragmentActivity*. The [definition of the *Adapter* class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter) states:

> An *Adapter* object acts as a bridge between an *AdapterView* and the
>   underlying data for that view. The *Adapter* provides access to the data
>   items. The *Adapter* is also responsible for making a *View* for each item
>   in the data set.

If you interpret a *Marker* as *View* on top of the map layer an *Adapter* would be suitable for bridging the underlaying data to being display on the map.

The problem is that the common pattern of the *CursorAdapter* in my example does not apply to the map case:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // Retrieve data from the cursor
    // Update the view holder with actual values
}
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Inflate XML layout for a list item
    // Prepare view holder
}
```

In order to work with this pattern a *Marker* must be equivalent to a row in a list view. Though, a marker is not inflated. The basic pattern is a follows and does not fit with the *Adapter*:

```
GoogleMap mMap;
// Prepare marker options from cursor data
mMap.addmarker(markerOptions);
```

How would you design such an *Adapter* class? You are welcome to post and discuss pseudo code.

Comment: In a listview, the dataset that has to be displayed is known beforehand and hence the cursor is chosen accordingly. But for markers, the infowindow is displayed only for one marker at a time and this is chosen based on which marker the user clicks, which is a random event  and hence you cannot know beforehand the datat to be displayed

Comment: @tony I am not aiming to create an adapter for the info window - [this already exists](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html). I talking about creating a new adapter for the *Marker* objects themselves.